# ASP.Net custom authentication with existing server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication

We have an existing user licensing server that is running via PHP. It allows for creation of users, checking if the provided username and password is valid, and updating a user.

We are creating a new ASP.Net website and want it to use this existing user PHP scripts/database to restrict access to portions of the ASP.Net website. Also there are web services that use the same login and password via basic authentication that we need to access as well from the ASP.Net server.

I am looking for a way for .Net to use the remote PHP scripts to validate login. And I need a way for the users login id and password to be available so I can use them to communicate with those existing web services from the ASP.Net server on their behalf.

Does anyone know how to go about getting this sort of thing done. Or any good tutorials or blogs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to run PHP and ASP.NET on the same server, and even in the same web application. You can also create .NET code that runs before and/or after each PHP request (with an `HttpModule`).

PHP under IIS just has a separate `HttpHandler` that invokes the cgi-bin process.

If you want to call a PHP page from an ASP.NET page, one approach is to use `Server.Execute()` -- although web services would certainly be cleaner from an architectural perspective.

Beyond that, for the actual authentication/authorization part of your question, the approach depends on the specifics of your implementation. You can certainly do things like share cookies between PHP and .aspx.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunatly they are different languages and php scripts cannot be used in an asp.net site. You would have to recreate your classes(scripts) but what you can do is use your existing database if its in mysql or any other.  That's the best you would be able to do as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

If those PHP web services respect some industry standard such as SOAP for example, you can simply consume them by generating strongly typed client proxies. If not, well, then you still have the good old [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) which allows you to send HTTP requests and read responses. It's as simple as:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "username", "john" },
        { "pwd", "secret" },
    };
    var result = client.UploadValues("http://foo.com/login.php", values);
    // TODO: do something with the result returned by the PHP script
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using stored procedures instead of PHP scripts? That way you don't have to write multiple instances of the same code and it can be used in .NET and PHP.